# Kernel upgrade to 4.15.0-33 breaks wifi

Tags: wireless, upgrade, kernel

Running Kubuntu 18.04.

Recently upgraded kernel to 4.15.0-33. This was part of normal upgrade.

But after the upgrade, networking is troublesome. I am not able to connect to any wifi network. I am not able to connect to any wired network. Bluetooth tethering does not work.

The only thing that works is USB tethering.

Under 4.15.0-33 kernel, `dkms status` produces no output and
`sudo lshw -c network` produces:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 40:b8:9a:2c:2f:4d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:37 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 58:20:b1:7e:67:36
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:30 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0900000-f0900fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

I rebooted into 4.15.0-29 kernel and wifi works properly.

Under 4.15.0-29 kernel, `dkms status` produces no output and
`sudo lshw -c network` produces:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 40:b8:9a:2c:2f:4d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.15.0-29-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:37 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 58:20:b1:7e:67:36
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0900000-f0900fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

Currently I am running 4.15.0-29. But is there any way I can boot into 4.15.0-33 and still get network access?

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of **dkms status** and **sudo lshw -c network**. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. Have edited the question with the output of these commands. Just a clarification, I ran the commands under 4.15.0-29 --- when I could connect to the net. Will it be useful to include the output under 4.15.0-33?

Comment: @heynnema I thought it would be a good idea to add the outputs under the new kernel, too. So, did that. Hope it is useful.

Comment: This is a current bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/comments/21